# How can I change the order of some string in a filename

Tags: string, bash, filenames

I have lots of files like these:

```
tf_CVBV6Z_CVSA1Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVBV5Z_CVSA2Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVBV4Z_CVSA3Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVBV3Z_CVSA4Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVBV2Z_CVSA5Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVBV1Z_CVSA6Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
```

and I want to change the order to end up like this:

```
tf_CVSA1Z_CVBV6Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVSA2Z_CVBV5Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVSA3Z_CVBV4Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVSA4Z_CVBV3Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVSA5Z_CVBV2Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVSA6Z_CVBV1Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
```

I tried the rename option but it does not work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What part is fixed? Can we match on the underscores?
What do do when the new file name already exists, or will that be impossible (files `tf_a_b_pws2.pcc1.sac` and `tf_b_a_pws2.pcc1.sac` both exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With perl's rename :

```
$ rename -n 's/(CV[^_]+)_(CV[^_]+)/$2_$1/' tf_CVSA1Z_CVBV6Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
tf_CVSA1Z_CVBV6Z_pws2_pcc1.sac -> tf_CVBV6Z_CVSA1Z_pws2_pcc1.sac
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>